# Confused About Stunned Investigators

Tags: mansions-of-madness

When an investigator is stunned I understand that it limits the moves from 2 to 1.  Optionally, the investigator can spend their action to remove the stun.  If I spend the action first, is the move limit still in effect until the next turn?  Or can I then move two times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the rulebook:

> Investigators: A stunned investigator only receives one  Movement Step
>   during his turn. If he becomes stunned  during his turn, he may not
>   take a second Movement Step....
>
> ....An investigator or monster may have multiple stun tokens on him,  and
>   may only discard one per turn (either during the Investigator  Trading
>   Step or the Monster Attack Step – see pages 10–11).
>
> **Keeper Turn in Detail**
>
> **Step 1** Investigator Trading Step
>
> ....After trading items, each stunned investigator may discard one of 
>   his stun tokens (see “Status Effects” on page 15)
>
> **Step 4** Monster Attack Step
>
> ....If a monster has a stun token on it, then the monster does not attack 
>   during this step. Instead, the keeper removes one stun token from the 
>   monster

And from the FAQ on the Fantasy Flight website:

> Q: Can stunned Investigators perform actions?
>
> A: Yes. A stunned investigator receives 1 movement step and 1 
>   action step on his turn.

So if the investigator is stunned at the beginning of their turn they can perform one movement step and 1 action step (which can be used as a Run Action that would allow them to move another time). There's nothing I see (in the base rulebook at least) that allows investigators to remove stun tokens with an action. Stun tokens on investigators are only removed at the end of the 'Investigator Trading Step' during the Keeper's Turn.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember that rule but since nothing would stop you from using your action as an extra move the effect would be the same. So I say yes that is allowed.